# xConnect Sitecore Context add custom facets to new contacts

Tags: xconnect

I am trying to create custom facets on new contacts.

I am using this code :

```
        using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            var model = client.Model;
            Contact contact = new Contact(new ContactIdentifier("external", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ContactIdentifierType.Known));
            client.AddContact(contact);


            MyConsumerProfileFacet facet = new MyConsumerProfileFacet ();
            facet.Email = "myemail@gmail.com";
            facet.LastName = "aaaaaaaa";
            facet.FirstName = "bbbbbbb";

             client.SetFacet(contact, MyConsumerProfileFacet .DefaultFacetKey, facet);

            client.Submit();

        }
```

On submit I have next exception : **The type of this instance does not correspond to any type in the model**

On xConnect I deployed my json model and it looks like :

```
"Types": {
    "X.Feature.DynamicsCrm.Facets.ConsumerProfileFacet": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "X.Feature.DynamicsCrm.Facets.ConsumerProfileFacet, X.Feature.DynamicsCrm, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "Websitegroup": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "Subscribetoportalnews": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "Subscribetoportalemail": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "Subscribetoportalblog": {
          "Type": "String"
        }, 
         "Email": {
      "Type": "String"
        }, 
       // other properties 
       }
   }
```

If I used default Facets it works perfectly.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you also post custom facet c# class? Have you patched also XConnect.Client with your custom facet? See last chapter of this article https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/managing-model/deployment.html . We had similar issue and this solved it

Comment: @PeterProchazka please add your answer, I just added my model into a config file and it works. I had before this issue but I forgot about it.. .

Comment: Glad I could help you Vlad. It was lucky shot or good gut feeling... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add your custom model into config file which will patch \App_Config\Sitecore\XConnect.Client.Configuration\Sitecore.XConnect.Client.config at the end.

Something similar to this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <xconnect>
    <runtime type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.RuntimeModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration">
        <schemas hint="list:AddModelConfiguration">
            <!-- value of 'name' property must be unique -->
            <schema name="documentationmodel" type="Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.StaticModelConfiguration,Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration" patch:after="schema[@name='collectionmodel']">
                <param desc="modeltype">Documentation.Model.CollectionModel, Documentation.Model</param>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </runtime>
    </xconnect>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

More information can be found here:
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/managing-model/deployment.html